# GCP Datastore Operation commit failed on resource

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, commit, jdo, persistentmanager

I am trying to delete and to create the same object (but with a new schema) in my datastore with this way (I repeat this procedure for each object that I have using queues):

```
// ... more code
try {
    tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    tx.begin();
    // Deleting the old object
    pm.deletePersistent(pm.getObjectById(Expediente.class, old.getKey().getId()));
    tx.commit();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    if (tx.isActive()) {
        tx.rollback();
    }
}finally{
    pm.close();
}


pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
try {
    tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    tx.begin();

    // Setting the new object
    pm.makePersistent(newObject);
    tx.commit();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    if (tx.isActive()) {
        tx.rollback();
    }
}finally{
    pm.close();
}
```

Ok, it is working fine but sometimes, randomly, I get this error and the object is not changed. Any suggestion?

PM org.datanucleus.transaction.Transaction commit
Grave: Operation commit failed on resource: com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreXAResource@4d621f11, error code UNKNOWN and transaction: [DataNucleus Transaction, ID=Xid=

Comment: how about looking at the log? the first thing you should do, and the exception thrown too ... why catch it otherwise?

Comment: This error is at the log. I can't catch this kind of error because it is with the datastore. When it happens, it does rollback the transaction. I'd like to know if it is because I am doing a lot of operations (delete and commit) with many queues...

Comment: That "error" is not the root cause. It is that something in the Google datastore fell apart, so look at that error which will (hopefully) tell you where the problem is.

Comment: Getting same Error org.datanucleus.transaction.Transaction commit: Operation commit failed on resource: com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreXAResource@3b0da870, error code UNKNOWN and transaction: [DataNucleus Transaction, ID=Xid=, enlisted resources=[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreXAResource@3b0da870]] (Transaction.java:155)